# Update Gradle in Grails project

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 3.0.5

After I create a project... at root project has folder .gradle with 2.3 version...

How to update that Gradle version?

I tried to download Grails 3.0.9 and create a new project..but it still use Gradle 2.3 version..

I tried to download Gradle 2.6 from this [link](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/) , because I am using windows...  I tried to run gradlew.bat ... and recreate-app with Grails 3.0.9 version...and i still get a new project with Gradle 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's defined in `gradle.properties`. If you change the version there (I recommend using 2.8 for the new features and speed improvements) you can use the wrapper that's there from Gradle 2.3 to generate a new wrapper for whatever version you're updating to; just run

```
gradlew.bat wrapper
```

or

```
./gradlew wrapper
```

if you were using Linux or OSX, and it will update the `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` scripts, and the wrapper files under `gradle/wrapper`.

Comment: oh...so everytime i run gradlew.bat ( windows )..it will automatically read gradle.properties?

Comment: Yes, and also `init.gradle`, `settings.gradle`, etc. if they exist. If you haven't used Gradle much, check out the intro material in [the User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).