# Can't get Micrometer Prometheus to Download Into my Grails 2 App

Tags: gradle, grails, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to set up prometheus in my grails 2 app, so I've come across using micrometer to do so. I attempted to follow the instructions here: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus where I put that compile line in the `BuildConfig.groovy`, then set up an endpoint to expose the metrics. However, the app fails to download the micrometer package with a ton of errors, starting with those below:

```
| Downloading: micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.0.0-rc.1.zip.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    problem while downloading module descriptor: http://search.maven.org/io/micrometer/micrometer-registry-prometheus/latest.release/micrometer-registry-prometheus-latest.release.pom: invalid sha1: expected=<!--

 computed=2aa3d0d4f6ea46d428e8f585cfb1d3a3bce05d17 (344ms)
        [FAILED     ] io.micrometer#micrometer-registry-prometheus;1.0.0-rc.1!micrometer-registry-prometheus.zip: invalid sha1: expected=<!--

 computed=2aa3d0d4f6ea46d428e8f585cfb1d3a3bce05d17 (241ms)
        [FAILED     ] io.micrometer#micrometer-registry-prometheus;1.0.0-rc.1!micrometer-registry-prometheus.zip: invalid sha1: expected=<html><head><meta computed=da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709 (4483ms)
        [FAILED     ] io.micrometer#micrometer-registry-prometheus;1.0.0-rc.1!micrometer-registry-prometheus.zip: invalid sha1: expected=<html><head><meta computed=da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709 (2241ms)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The 1.0.0-rc.1 version seems suspect. The latest release is `1.54` See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-registry-prometheus/1.5.4

Comment: @checketts I'm using the latest release in gradle with `compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:latest.release'` like it says on the website so not sure why it would be pulling the wrong one

Comment: How does it behave when when you use a specific version?

Comment: @checketts I get the same errors if I put in 1.5.4: https://i.gyazo.com/74cb8cfcfde7286265f4ddde32f1a3ad.jpg

Comment: You are getting https errors. Maven central requires https now. You need to upgrade your maven or build tool or maven central property.

Comment: @checketts Do you know if this is something tied to the app or if this is how it's installed locally? I can't upgrade the app itself yet. We're working on moving grails from 2 to 3 then to 4 but it's a slow process. I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't require that upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not used grails. Does it use its own build tool? Or Gradle?

Comment: It uses it's own build too, at least locally I know. You just run a `run-app` command and it compiles and starts the app. It just uses Gradle as its package manager I believe. Not sure if it has a packaged maven or if it runs of a local version of it

Comment: I do have locally maven version 3.6.3 installed which I believe is the most recent one

Comment: You need to upgrade your project's gradle: Something along https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360256/update-gradle-in-grails-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talks with @checketts and some internal discussions with the package creators, the problem was that maven in the grails app was using a non-https version of the repository link. However, maven requires https for most public repositories now.

Luckily with grails you can define your own repositories in the `BuildConfig.groovy`, and if not explicity defined there it just has a default address it was using. So adding the required repository with an https tag fixed it: `mavenRepo "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"`